# FreeNAS 8 connection limit

Tags: truenas, afp

I have an issue with FreeNAS 8 where if more than 20 users try and connect to the server at the same time the 21st cannot and the login screen will shake as if to show the user the password is incorrect.

I have researched into this issue and apparently with FreeNAS 7 there was a way of changing `command_args="-F ${afpd_config}"` via the webgui file editor however as there is no webgui file editor I have to ssh into my server, locate the same file given in the FreeNAS 7 example (etc/rc.d/afpd) so to alter the amount of connections to the server. The only issue I have is that I cannot seem to find the code to change the connection limit.

Has anyone else had this issue of a connection limit to AFP shares in FreeNAS 8 or knows where I can alter the code to allow more than 20 concurrent connections?

Perhaps the location of this variable is different or it has been written differently in FreeNAS 8 to FreeNAS 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the command line at the console:

```
mount -uw / 
cd /conf/base/etc/local
Edit /conf/base/etc/local/netatalk.conf
Uncomment the line that says: **#AFPD_MAX_CLIENTS=20**
Change the 20 to the number of users you want
Save the file
Reboot
```

Comment: So an update of my day - FreeNAS appeared to be working perfectly with max clients set to 100 however with only around 35 in my office I have had complaints that people can't connect or they get an invalid password error.

So I disconnect and reconnect and find they are now connected and I get the issue.

I will try a higher number for max clients tomorrow and see if the problem persists. Perhaps max clients refers to connections to each AFP share, not connections to the server. As I have alot more AFP shares than users.

Comment: Updated to 1000 max clients and now fully restarted the server - see what today brings!